# Android OpenGL - Shape Transparency (No in Texture)

Tags: android, opengl-es

This is my first question...

I've a square (triangle strip) with a texture (.png).
This .png have smooth corners like a play card.
The four extremities (corners) are transparent.

When draw the square, in the corners, i see the white color of the shape.
(Like a background behind the texture)
My question is:

How can i draw a transparent color for the shape, but mantain the color of the texture with a full apha?

(If i set transparent colors.... then also the texture become transparent)

How can i separate the two contexts?

Thanks in advance.. and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must use a texture format with alpha channel.

Then if you are using fixed function pipeline, you must enable blending.
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

If you are not using fixed function pipeline, please share the fragment shader code; and a little more details on how you are using it.

Comment: Thanks!!!

You've right!
with this the problem is solved:

glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);